# Windows gVim edit file from Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, vim, batch, gvim

I have a Windows batch file that I use to edit files using Notepad++

```
@echo off

if [%1] == [] (

    C:\PROG\Notepad++Portable\Notepad++Portable.exe

) else (

    C:\PROG\Notepad++Portable\Notepad++Portable.exe %CD%\%1

)
```

Which works fine and I am trying to do the same for gVim (the Windows version of Linux's Vim).

```
@echo off

if [%1] == [] (

    C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe

) else (

    C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe %CD%\%1

)
```

But the part where I need it to edit/create a document as an argument doesn't seem to work for gVim.

It works fine for Notepad++

```
C:\PROG\Notepad++Portable\Notepad++Portable.exe \directory\name\editFile.txt
```

Then when I try in gVim

```
C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe \directory\name\editFile.txt
```

It opens up without acknowledging the argument.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not very familiar with batch file scripting and how the Windows command interpreter processes white space but I found that enclosing the *entire path* of the command in double quotes worked for me when I was creating a batch file for the [ItsAllText](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/) extension for Firefox:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe" "%1"
```

Comment: This is quite interesting I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Something I just realised is it is only the Graphical Vim that isn't allowing me to edit files via the command line (gvim.exe)

However the Standard Vim seems to work perfectly (vim.exe). I have updated my Windows Batch Script to use this instead and it is working fine

```
@echo off

if [%1] == [] (

    C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Vim\vim74\vim.exe

) else (

    C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Vim\vim74\vim.exe %CD%\%1

)
```

Comment: `vim -g file` - `-g` Run using GUI (like "gvim")